# Rails access folder in public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have such structure(for example):

```
 public
   art_im
     folder1
        img01.jpg
```

what i need to write, to access this img01.jpg in tag?
i try

```
= image_tag("#{Rails.root}/public/art_im/images_#{@graphics.id}/#{@grp.id}.jpg", :alt => "#{@art.nr}")
```

but i get in html 
`<img alt="lalala" src="/home/prog/project/Shop/public/art_im/images_32/214800.jpg">`

but how to link on my server, and get this images?

Comment: You might want to look at the `paperclip` gem, which automates all of this icky file stuff.

Comment: @bdares this is catalogue.... no paperclip wanna there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your app is run by webserver, its webroot will be the `public` directory. So, this should work:

```
= image_tag("/art_im/images_#{@graphics.id}/#{@grp.id}.jpg", :alt => "#{@art.nr}")
```

Comment: i use nginx+passenger.... but if i put in public logo.jpg and acees domain.com/logo.jpg all is ok

Comment: Well, are you absolutely sure this file exists at this path?

Comment: @brabertaser1992: checked on my machine, it worked. I use nginx+unicorn, though. What are the versions of ruby/rails/nginx/passenger?

Comment: I still think that there's no file in the filesystem at this path. Passenger should not even see this request, because nginx would have served it.

Comment: yes, one of 1000 didn't exists... i have entered this one... with other all is ok